# format change when upgade from yadcf 0.6.9 to 0.8.8

Tags: yadcf

I am finally upgrading the yadcf version on my site from 0.6.9 to 0.8.8 and am seeing some change in behavior I'm not sure how to control. (I'm also upgrading from datatables 1.9.4 to 1.10.10)

See the 0.6.9 version at [my production site](http://steeplechasers.org/scoretility/viewstandings/?club=fsrc&series=grandprix&desc=Frederick%20Steeplechasers%20Running%20Club%20-%202015%20grandprix&year=2015) and the 0.8.8 version at [my sandbox site](http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/viewstandings/?club=fsrc&series=grandprix&desc=Frederick%20Steeplechasers%20Running%20Club%20-%202015%20grandprix&year=2015)

The difference I see is when inspect (chrome) around the Gender external filter, in 0.6.9 the `<div id="yadcf-filter-wrapper-_rrwebapp_filtergender" class="yadcf-filter-wrapper">` and in 0.8.8 `<div id="yadcf-filter-wrapper-_rrwebapp_filtergender">`, i.e., the div is not given .yadcf-filter-wrapper.

In any case, can someone advise how to get the production / 0.6.9 behavior of having all these on a single line?

**Update 1:** The sandbox page is simplified [here](http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/_teststandings/). Note this is equivalent to the production page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The since its your external container that you placing the yadcf filters at, the proper solution should be for you to set your containers with a `display: inline-block;` css rule and thats it.

You can add a class to your `_rrwebapp_filtergender` and `_rrwebapp_filterdivision` and set a rule for that class `display: inline-block;`

Relying on your internal style should come before relying on third party css styling.